# Problemas com bibliotecas do python, ChatBot

Tags: python, chatbot

Estou com problemas na biblioteca do Python, especificamente o ChatBot, 
o erro é o seguinte:

```
from chatterbot import Chatbot
ImportError: cannot import name 'Chatbot' "
```

Aqui está meu código:

```
from chatterbot import Chatbot
import pyttsx
import speech_recognition as sr

en = pyttsx.init()
en.setProperty('voice',b'brazil')
rec = sr.Recognizer()

class BotFalante(Chatbot):
    def escuta(self,frase=None):
        try:
            with sr.Microphone() as mic:
                fala = rec.listen(mic)
            frase = rec.recognize_google(fala,language='pt')
            frase = frase.replace('aprendi','aprende')
            print(frase)
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print('Deu erro na identificação')
            return ('')
        return super().escuta(frase=frase)

    def fala(self,frase):
        en.say(frase)
        en.runAndWait()
        super().fala(frase)

Bot = BotFalante('Zuleide')
while True:
    frase = Bot.escuta()
    resp = Bot.pensa(frase)
    Bot.fala(resp)
    if resp == ('falou'):

        break
```

Comment: Instalou o chatbot? com o pip install chatterbot ? Da uma olhadinha aqui: https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html

Comment: eu instalei com sudo pip3 install chatterbot (uso ubuntu)

Comment: pois verifica se tá instalado python -m chatterbot --version. Se não tiver e usa umbunto usa o comando. pip3 install git+git://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot.git@master

Comment: quando eu dou o comando python -m chatterbot --version. , volta isso: /usr/bin/python: No module named chatterbot, mesmo que eu já tenha instalado igual voce disse, dá esse mesmo erro

Comment: então o módulo não esta instalado. Uma dica que posso dar pra lher ajudar. Instala o Anaconda no unbuntu. Vai evitar esses problemas de instalação e versão. https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux

Comment: por algum acaso voce nao instalou fora do ambiente virtual?, se vc estiver rodando o programa dentro de um ambiente virtual e executou o pip fora nao vai dar certo

Answer (score 0):

Você nomeou seu chatterbot de chatterbot.py e depois importou do chatterbot muda o nome dele pra qualquer outro e deve funcionar.

Comment: mudei o nome do arquivo e não adiantou nada :/

Comment: você tem que apagar também o chatterbot.pyc que foi gerado

Answer (score 0):

Onde estiver `Chatbot` muda para `ChatBot`:

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot

class BotFalante(ChatBot):
```